# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.....?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi guys I always got this error from my site and it keeps bugging me.I've been trying to figure out the cause of this error but I can't really figure it out.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
at BasePage.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

And on my basepage I only got this code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        Page.Theme = "Something"
        If (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0) Then
            Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        If Me.Title = "Untitled Page" Then
            Throw New Exception("Page title cannot be ""Untitled Page"".")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

According to the stacktrace this always happens on my basepage preinit event.What do you think is the problem here guys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

I love guessing games, they are so fun.

`Request.UserAgent` is null?

Comment: Yep. Not every Requesting Agent sends this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug the error - run your project in the VS and put breakpoint in the `Page_PreInit` method. Then execute each line step by step (F10) and you will figure out where and why the error occurres. Also you can use Ctrl+Alt+E to turn on breaking on any thrown exception - this will show you the exact line.

Answer (score 0):

Likely one of the following values is `Nothing` / `null`

- `Request.UserAgent`
- `Request.Browser`
- `Request.Browser.Adapters`

You will need to check these values for `Nothing` before using them in order to protect yourself against this exception

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to tell without an exact line number, but upon reading the MSDN Documents, your reference to [`Request.Browser.Adapters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.adapters.aspx) looks like it may be causing problems, as MSDN states that this property is used for infrastructure and isn't meant to be accessed directly from your code.